# Can't return a value with ZeroRPC NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, oop, callback, zerorpc

I am running in a problem with Javascript and the library [ZeroRPC](http://www.zerorpc.io/)
I created a server this way:

**Server:**

```
var zerorpc = require('zerorpc');

var server = new zerorpc.Server({
    hello: function(name, reply) {
        reply(null, 'Hello, ' + name);
    }
});

server.bind('tcp://0.0.0.0:4242');
```

**Client**

```
var zerorpc = require('zerorpc');

var client = new zerorpc.Client();
client.connect('tcp://127.0.0.1:4242');

var result = client.invoke('hello', 'RPC', function(error, res, more) {
    //console.log(res); //WORKS ! logs 'Hello, RPC'
    return res; //returns undefined
});

console.log(result); //undefined :(
```

I don't understand why I cannot return this value from the client.invoke call. Am I missing something out ?

Comment: The remote call is *asynchronous*. The `.invoke()` function call returns basically immediately. Later, when the RPC response is received, the platform calls your callback function.

Comment: @Pointy thanks! I’m not yet able to work with asynchronous JavaScript. How can I wait for the reply ? Promise or await ?

Comment: Well that callback function you pass to `client.invoke()` *does* wait for the reply; anything you do inside that callback happens after the response has been received. Asynchronous programming is extremely common and idiomatic in JavaScript.